# How to get a semicolon as data inserted in Cassandra using cql-exec

Tags: cassandra, cql

As part of my local setup, using Intellij, I execute a setup.cql file as part of the build. However, I need to have a semicolon in one of the fields, as part of the data in that field. As expected, the semicolon ; is recognized and stops the execution.

I have searched how to escape this or how to work around this, but no luck so far. Can anybody help here, or just maybe confirm "what you're trying here is not possible"?

The query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (c1, c2, c3) VALUES ('value1', 'semi ; colon', 'value3');
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to escape anything.  I created a simple table and ran the `INSERT` that you posted above.  Works fine:

```
> CREATE TABLE semiTest (c1 TEXT primary key, c2 TEXT, c3 TEXT);
> INSERT INTO semiTest (c1, c2, c3) VALUES ('value1', 'semi ; colon', 'value3');
> SELECT * FROm semitest;

 c1     | c2           | c3
--------+--------------+--------
 value1 | semi ; colon | value3

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying this out. Can you explain how you ran this query? I do have success when just executing this in the console(Intellij in this case) but not when doing this as part of a build and having it executed by cql-exec.

Comment: @Carnifex ok, what is cql-exec?  I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: cql-exec is part of Mojo's Cassandra Maven plugin to execute cql statements from Maven.

Comment: @Carnifex Can you post a link to your GitHub repo with your pom.xml file?